# Access a ng-repeat variable in a controller

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Here is what I currently have:

**HTML**

```
            <center><li ng-repeat = "x in items | orderBy: 'priority'"> 
            <!-- color code priorities -->
            <span ng-style="cmplt" ng-class="{ red: x.type == 'Work', blue: x.type == 'Personal' }">
                <b>{{ x.name }}</b></span>
            <span ng-class="{ yourChore: x.assignedTo == username} ">
                - {{ x.type }} (Priority {{ x.priority }}) Assigned by {{ x.creator }} to {{ x.assignedTo }}
            </span>&nbsp;&nbsp;

 <!-- When task is completed, user can click this button to mark it as such -->
            <button type="button" ng-click="cmplt={color: 'gray', 'text-decoration': 'line-through'} ; 
                markAs(this)">Completed</button>
            <div ng-class="{ red: x.completed == true }"> Hello</div>
            <button type="button" ng-click = "comment = true">Comment</button>
            <div ng-show="comment"><textarea rows="3" columns="50" ng-model="x.comments"></textarea></div>
            <div>{{ x.comments }}</div>
        </li></center>
```

**JavaScript**

```
    $scope.markAs = function(repeatScope){
    if (!repeatScope.completed){
        repeatScope.completed = true;
    }
    else {
        repeatScope.completed = false;
    }
};
```

The object that is being repeated has a boolean value in it that by default is marked false, but when a button is clicked should re-evaluate to true. The problem is this doesn't happen (stays false) and I'm not sure why based off of my code.

Comment: Have you tried passing markAs(x)?

Comment: Why wouldn't "this" work, however?

Comment: @devqon Can you post that as an answer so OP can accept it?

Comment: OP, I believe it is a scope issue. The joy of angular is that there are so many scopes that get created, so it is sometimes hard to figure out which scope is being used at any one time. When you ng-repeat, the x scope is defined. When using 'this' it's not evaluated until the click.

Comment: @Owen you mean that a scope is created for the ng-repeat and the x var is only declared in it right ? Look at the two parts scope hierarchy and scope event propagations in this docs to get a better understanding of scopes : https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/scope

Comment: @Ajv2324, a bit explain why it not work with _this_: in template - _this_ refers to current scope, `ngRepeat` create own scope, so _this_ is scope where defined nested _ngRepeat_ variables as special, like _$index_, _$last_ and etc, or user defined like _x_ in your case, so _this_ can work if inside function you check not _completed_ but _x.completed_

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can pass in the current element by what you defined in the `ng-repeat`:

```
<li ng-repeat="x in items"> <!-- reference to x within the repeat scope -->
    <button type="button" 
            ng-click="cmplt={color: 'gray', 'text-decoration': 'line-through'}; markAs(x)">
        Completed
    </button>
</li>
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to pass `x` which is the current item in your ng-repeat and not `this`.

```
<button type="button" ng-click="cmplt={color: 'gray', 'text-decoration': 'line-through'} ; 
            markAs(x)">Completed</button>
```

Answer (score 1):

The solution is pretty simple, try something like this :

As you used

```
ng-repeat = "x in items"
```

x will reference each repeated item.

```
markAs(x)
```

Will launch the function with the "right" x in parameters.